# upgradesstables not working in dse cassandra upgrade

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am upgrading DSE cassndra from 4.8.16 to 5.0.15 , but when i execute `nodetool upgradesstables` I am getting below error:

```
error: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
-- StackTrace --
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: commitlog directory '/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.resolveAndCheckDirectory(DatabaseDescriptor.java:798)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:535)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:131)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.checkJobs(NodeProbe.java:274)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.upgradeSSTables(NodeProbe.java:328)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.nodetool.UpgradeSSTable.execute(UpgradeSSTable.java:54)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:253)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:167)
```

Comment: Your `nodetool` is unable to act on the `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog` directory. What are the permissions of `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`?

Comment: I am using my defined commitlog directory, not /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog. I confirmed the location in cassandra.yaml

Comment: `nodetool` is clearly using `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`. What is the value of `commitlog_directory` in `cassandra.yaml`?

Comment: Its  /sbclocal/apps/data/commitlog in cassandra.yaml.. Nodes were up and running fine , but only upgrade is failing.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it looks like `nodetool` isn't using your `cassandra.yaml`. Perhaps you've updated the wrong file?

Comment: what is the installation type? packages or tar?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, My installation directory and package directory are different. I am running the command from package directory which is why its picking the wrong path. To counter this I set the property "CASSANDRA_CONF" to correct path, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Commit logs from the previous version incompatible with the new version.
To flush the commit log of the old installation use

```
nodetool -h hostname drain
```

also check commit log directory path in cassandra.yml.